# Wait for initialization of lazy loaded state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a button and an `onClick` handler. The first think I do in the `onClick` handler is

```
if (this.state.lazyLoadedData === undefined) {
    await this.loadData();
}
```

My problem is that if I click the button two times quickly, `this.loadData()` get's executed twice.

What is the typescript/react idiomatic way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way is to use an explicit promise for accessing lazily loaded data, always.

declare and initialize it somewhere

```
loadDataPromise: Promise<YourDataType> | undefined = undefined;
```

then, in onclick handler

```
if (!this.loadDataPromise) {
    this.loadDataPromise = this.loadData();
}

this.loadDataPromise.then(yourDataHere => {
});
```

Comment: Where should `loadDataPromise` live? This code is part of a react component. If it lives in the components state, then I think `loadDataPromise` should actually look like `this.setState({ loadDataPromise: this.loadData() })` and `setState` itself is asynchronous so there's still a problem, no? If I put it as a regular member variable, is that safe? Arn't components recreated sometimes? Won't the `loadDataPromise` variable get lost in that case?

Comment: Hmm.. read up [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00). Maybe it's safe to have "`this`" hold `loadDataPromise`?

Comment: Yes it should be safe to have it in the component, initialized in the constructor. Not sure about React, but if it's initialized with `undefined` in the constructor, I assume it will work even when the component is recreated.

Comment: I went for this, but did `yourDataHere = await this.loadDataPromise;` Thanks!